# Python write a new csv file by filtering selected rows from an existing csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7

just a question, I was trying to write selected rows from a .csv file to a new .csv file, but there is an error.

The test.csv file that I was trying to read is like this(two columns):

```
2013-9     1
2013-10    2
2013-11    3
2013-12    4
2014-1     5
2014-2     6
2014-3     7
2014-4     8
2014-5     9
```

Since I only want year 2014, here is my code:

```
import re
import csv

write_flag=0
string_storage=[]
rad_file=open('year.csv')

for rad_line in rad_file:
        if write_flag==1:
                string_storage.append(rad_line)
        if (rad_line.has_key('2014')):
                write_flag=1
        if (rad_line.has_key('2013')):
                write_flag=0
rad_file.close()

out_file = open("try.csv","w")
for temp_string in string_storage:
    out_file.write(temp_string)
out_file.close()
```

however, the error is:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'has_key'

Have no idea of the correct way to program this, please help me who is a new python user
Thanks

Comment: why would you use python for this? why not just use `grep`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using the csv module anyway, why not write the file as you are reading it in:

```
import csv

with open('in.csv', 'r') as i, open('out.csv', 'w') as o:
   r = csv.reader(i, delimiter='\t')
   w = csv.writer(o, delimiter='\t')
   for row in r:
      if row[0].split('-')[0] == '2014':
          w.write(row)
```

Comment: Great answer but the csv module wants to manage line endings itself. For python 2, open in binary mode, for python 3 in text mode but with `newline=''`.

Answer (score 2):

The error could be "fixed" by changing `has_key` to `startswith`, but more importantly, the way the program is currently written, you'll skip the first line which starts with 2014, and include the first line of subsequent groups that starts with 2013. Is that really what you want?

If instead you simply want to keep all lines that begin with 2014, then:

```
with open('year.csv') as rad_file, open("try.csv","w") as out_file:
    header = next(rad_file)
    out_file.write(header)
    for rad_line in rad_file:
        if rad_line.startswith('2014'):
            out_file.write(rad_line)
```

By processing each line as they are read, you avoid accumulating lines in the list `string_storage`, thus saving memory. That can be important when processing large files.

---

Also, if you use a [`with-statement`](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) to open your files, then the file will be automatically closed for you when the flow of execution leaves the with-statement.

---

Note that in Python2, `dicts` have a `has_key` method to check if the dict has a certain key.

The code raised an error because `rad_line` is a string not a dict.

The `has_key` method was removed in Python3. In modern versions of Python2 such as Python2.7, you never need to use `has_key` since `key in dict` is preferred over `dict.has_key(key)`.

Comment: :another question, since I also have headers of my original csv file, for example they are date and number, how can I reserve the headers for the new created csv file?

Comment: I've added code showing how you could read the `header` first and write it to `out_file` before looping through the rest of `rad_file`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [string.find](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) or regular expressions to find a substring in a string.

So instead of

```
if (rad_line.has_key('2014')):
```

you can do:

```
if (rad_line.find('2014') <> -1):
```

Comment: another question, since I also have headers of my original csv file, for example they are date and number, how can I reserve the headers for the new created csv file?